# Cloud functions cron job: How to manage the nested collection's data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to trigger the scheduled task to the nested collection data using cloud functions cron job.

What I want to achieve is, if the timestamp value in "limit" field is later than the current time, "status" field will be added with the value "expired" in the nested collection.

The parent collection name is "OrdersUser" and the child collection name is "Orders".
And I want to manage the documents in "Orders" collection.
[image]
[image]

The scheduled task runs every one minute.

After I deployed, I got an error in the firebase console.

> id is not defined.

I thought I could use wild card in the cloud functions, so I used {id} to refer the nested documents. But I couldn't.

I want to query all the data in ”Orders” collection.
How can I fix this issue?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore()
const ref = functions.firestore

exports.statusOrdersUser = functions.runWith( { memory: '2GB' }).pubsub.schedule('* * * * *').onRun((context) => {

    // Consistent timestamp
    const now = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
    
    // Query all documents ready to perform
    //id is not defined.
    const queryOrdersUser = db.collection('OrdersUser').doc({id}).collection('Orders').where('limit', '<=', now)
    

    return queryOrdersUser.get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {

                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    const promises = []

                    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                        promises.push(doc.ref.update({ status: 'expired' }));
                    });

                    return Promise.all(promises);
                }
            });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore does not support wildcard operations for document IDs.  If you want to query a subcollection, you need to provide the specific ID of the document where it is nested.  It's not clear how your function is supposed to know exactly which subcollection to query, since it doesn't receive any arguments or have any context.

If you want to query **all** of the subcollections named "Order", no matter where they are nested anywhere in your database, you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) for that.

Comment: I want to query all of the sub collections. In this case, is this the correct way to grab all the data in Orders collection?

Comment: Yes, you can use a collection group query that way.